# External JS function onload colliding with user functions onload

Tags: javascript

When you need to fire several functions when the page loads, you can handle it using something like this:

```
function myfunction() {
    alert('My function!');
}

function pctaddLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

pctaddLoadEvent(myfunction);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SSEhr/

This works ok if you fire the function you need to fire using the `pctaddLoadEvent` function. BUT, if that piece of code is intended to be inserted on different pages using an external JS file I need to keep in mind the robustness of my code, and lets say somebody include theexamplecode.js in their web site, BUT their also have some javascript on their web page, and they have something like:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert('user function');
    //and some other user functions
}
```

That will break my code as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KuTxh/4/).

So in a few words, how can I start my function onload without concerning about eventual user functions?

PS. I cant use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I think that issue could be solved by using namespacing of functions 
try this out [javascript namespacing](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/)